how to selected photos in android photo picker
Hey i need help regarding android photopicker
in this i select few images and able to show them in imageview
but i want to replace few images from those
i have list of selecteduri but no know parameter to pass selected uri to show that these images are selected
have anyone worked on this ?
this is how i am launching photopicker
pickMultipleMedia.launch(
                PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
                    .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly)
                    .build())


    private val pickMultipleMedia =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(5)) { uri: List<Uri>? ->
            if(uri!=null) {
                if (uri.isNotEmpty()) {
                    viewModel.multipleUris.value = uri
                }
            }
        }

no idea, because no way to pass selected image uri's

i want to replace few images from those i have list of selecteduri but no know parameter to pass selected uri to show that these images are selected ? Sorry, i do not understand a word of this. Abacadabra.

i mean,
Let's say i have selected 3 images and show it in my view
and lates i want to edit them i.e., i want to remove 2nd image and add other images,
so when again i open photopicker, it should show selected images.
@blackapps

Photo pickers dont show images or select them again that you picked before.
